# Hidden Markov Model probability of producing a sequence

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Suppose that we have two models for a 2-state HMM and both have two output symbols: $A$ and $B$.

**Model 1:**

- Transition probabilities: $a_{11}=0.6$, $a_{12}=0.4$, $a_{21}=0.0$, $_{22}=1.0$.
- Output probabilities: $_1()=0.45$, $_1()=0.55$, $_2()=0.5$, $_2()=0.5$.
- Initial probabilities: $_1=0.4$, $_2=0.6$.

**Model 2:**

- Transition probabilities: $a_{11}=0.2$, $a_{12}=0.8$, $a_{21}=0.0$, $_{22}=1.0$.
- Output probabilities: $_1()=0.2$, $_1()=0.8$, $_2()=0.6$, $_2()=0.4$.
- Initial probabilities: $_1=0.7$, $_2=0.3$.

Which model is more likely to produce the observation sequence $\{A, B, A\}$?

Comment: This seems doable, if a bit tedious. What's your problem?

Comment: I am new to Markov Chains and I want to know how can I produce the probability of the sequence in both the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can answer this samll problem with the basic version of forward algorithm, described in the famous tutorial paper [A tutorial on hidden Markov models and selected applications in speech recognition](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf) by Lawrence Rabiner. The interesting part of the paper for you is on page 6 :

[image]

Using an old code i had on my computer I get :
$$p({A, B, A}|\mathrm{Model} 1) \approx 0.1291, $$
while
$$p({A, B, A}|\mathrm{Model} 2) \approx 0.0817. $$

Thus Model 1 is more likely to generate this sequence.